# Creating an "object" of an interface

Tags: java, object, interface

Today I had a bit of an argument with a friend who claimed that an interface object can be created. When I said that it's impossible, he showed me the following piece of code, which seemed similar to anonymous classes.Now the question is, what's the right answer?

```
public interface I {
    public void f();
}

public class InterfaceTest {
    public static void main(String []args){
        new I(){
            @Override
            public void f() {
                System.out.println("HELLO");                
            }           
        };
    }
}
```

Can this really be called creating an interface "object"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is creating an instance of an anonymous class that implements the interface.

Here's the definitive answer from the [Java Language Specification, section 15.9](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.9):

> Both unqualified and qualified class instance creation expressions may
>   optionally end with a class body. Such a class instance creation
>   expression declares an anonymous class (§15.9.5) and creates an
>   instance of it.

Comment: Exactly... That's what I thought when I first saw this... I have used this sort of a thing many times for creating threads.

Comment: One more thing... The anonymous class that is created... is it said that it implements the interface because it overrides the methods in the interface?

Comment: @aps, Yes ofcourse, implementing an interface means overriding the abstract methods in the interface.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is (an *instance* of) an anonymous class.

Answer (score 0):

This is anonymous class creation. The class of the instance created above extends java.lang.Object and implements the interface I. So, technically, the above code creates an Object object.

Comment: The object's class is an anonymous class that *extends* Object.