# Why Java interface can be instantiated in these codes?

Tags: java, class, interface, instantiation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Creating an “object” of an interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7586277/creating-an-object-of-an-interface)

I am new to Java. Based on my understanding:

- We cannot instantiate an `Interface`. We can only instantiate a `class` which implements an `interface`.
- The `new` keyword is used to create an object from a class.

However, when I read the source codes of some Java programs, I found that sometimes an Interface is instantiated. For example:

**Example 1:**

```
JButtonObject.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        //codes
    }
});
```

**Example 2:**

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
{
    public void run()
    {
        //codes
    }
});
```

In the example at above, ActionListener and Runnable are both Java interface. May I know why they can be instantiated in these codes?

What is the purpose of instantiating an Interface? Refer to [this example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html), it seems that we should create an instance of a class which implement the interface.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That code does not instantiate an interface, but rather an anonymous class which implements `ActionListener` or `Runnable`.

> An *anonymous class* is a local class without a name. An anonymous class
>   is defined and instantiated in a single succinct expression using the
>   *new* operator.

The code is creating an instance of `ActionListener` anonymously, which means the class does not actually have any name.

After compiling that class, you can see a class `YourClass$1.class` in the output. The `$1` simply means that class is an anonymous class and the number `1` is generated by the compiler. When you have two anonymous classes, it will have something like `YourClass$1.class` and `YourClass$2.class` in the compiled classes.

**See**

- [Anonymous Classes](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/jnut/ch03_12.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Above example does not create new instance of interface - after new keyword there is implementation method for current interface. Read more about anonymous class.

Answer (score 0):

This form is just a shorthand to make it easier to create an object that implements an Interface. It's not the interface itself being instantiated, but rather an `Object implements Runnable` for example.