# "new" keyword with Comparator Interface

Tags: java

I got a question in my interview that while sorting objects of generic class(lets say objects of an "Employee class" which contains variable "EmpId" and "EmpName")when I use comparator in my Collection.sort() mothod then I need to use "new" keyword along with the comparator. We all know that comparator is an interface and it can not be instantiated. So how and why are we using the "new" keyword with it? As I found this question very interesting I thought of sharing it with all of you. Any help is appreciated. Here is the portion of sample code I am posting:-

```
ArrayList<Employee> emp= new ArrayLisy<Employee>();
Collection.sort(emp, new Comparator(){
    public int compare(emp e1, emp e2)
    {
        if(e1.getId>e2.getId)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        if(e1.getId<e2.getId)
        {
            return -1;
        }
        else
            return 0;
    }
})
```

My question is why are we using "new" keyword with Comparator interface here? Thanks

Comment: Look up "anonymous class". The code declares an unnamed class that implements Comparator and is only used to create one object, the sort argument.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan actually, it is named. Create an anonymous class instance and do `obj.getClass().getName()` and you'll see what I mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are getting confused by thinking that how can we create the object of interface - but that is just [anonymous class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html) being implemented

```
 new Comparator() { // anonymous class body    
        public int compare(emp e1, emp e2) {
            if (e1.getId > e2.getId) {
                return 1;
            }
            if (e1.getId < e2.getId) {
                return -1;
            } else
                return 0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please format your code. I realise you just copied the OP's code but it takes little effort for format it and it shows the OP how it's done.

Comment: @BoristheSpider yeah I should have done that earlier - formatting done now

Comment: guys.Thanks for the answer. Big help. Also I did not know the concept of "Anonymous Classes" so I learned a new thing today. Now this concept is clear to me. Thank you all.

Answer (score 3):

That code does not instantiate an interface, but rather an anonymous class which implements Comparator

An anonymous class is a local class without a name. An anonymous class is defined and instantiated in a single succinct expression using the new operator.

Answer Taken from this [Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11069056/why-java-interface-can-be-instantiated-in-these-codes)